# Duplicate declarations of permission with different maxSdkVersions

Tags: android

While updating the apk file to google play store started getting this error **Duplicate declarations of permission android.permission.INTERNET with different maxSdkVersions**. Internet permission is only there in app manifest file and corresponding modules.

Also recently there is no SDK update as well, like play services or any third party.
The app does not define maxSdkVersions as well.

If any of you might have faced the similar issue please update.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem occurs when you have declared a permission in your manifest that is also declared in one of the library that you are using. To rectify this issue you have to find that permission in all your libraries's manifests files. When you find it then remove one of them in your main Manifest like this:

[can't upload apk: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE with different maxSdkVersions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712542/cant-upload-apk-read-external-storage-with-different-maxsdkversions)

Comment: Are you sure you have checked manifests of all the libraries that you are using in your app?

Comment: Thanks Hassan, yes I did.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here that is worked for us:

```html
 <uses-permission-sdk-23 tools:node="removeAll"/>
```

Note you have to check that your app is not using sdk-23 specifically in your libraries.