# Play store publish error - how to validate

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, publish

my customer manages google play store account by another department. We do not have direct access to playstore account. When we send the apk it is returned with message

"Duplicate declarations of permission android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE with different maxSDKVersions"

is there any tool / way we can check play store acceptability before sending it for actual release ?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a tool does not exist. If you think about it, it would have to be a server side tool, otherwise it couldn't be kept up to date when Google Play changes their servers. And if it was a server side tool, you would have to access it through the Google Play Publishing API. Which you would need Play console access to use.

I would suggest you ask the other department to create you an API account or add a user for the Play console which has the right to publish to Alpha and Beta but not to production. Then you can test your APK using the Alpha track. See [the help docs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691) for the different levels of permissions you can give to users in the Play Console.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem occurs when you have declared a permission in your manifest that is also declared in one of the library that you are using. To rectify this issue you have to find that permission in all your libraries's manifests files. When you find it then remove one of them in your main Manifest like this:
[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712542/cant-upload-apk-read-external-storage-with-different-maxsdkversions)

also try below. i hav'nt try it by myself.

```
 <uses-permission-sdk-23 tools:node="removeAll"/>
```